# Comparing 2 JSONObjects

Tags: android, json

My question was like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919343/php-getting-count-of-how-many-x-and-y-in-a-row-then-getting-other-data-of-x-and

But then i thought about doing the job from Android Part. So i have 2 JSONObjects which generated from php. First object has "value" and "total" arrays. Second one has "name", "surname" and "number" and a few more arrays. Now i need to compare number from second JSONObject and value from first. I tried some loops, but it creates double as expected. Here is my onPostExecute method:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
         pDialog.dismiss();
         try {
             JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
             JSONObject jsonObj2 = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

             // Getting JSON Array node
             sonuc = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_BASLIK);

             // looping through All Contacts
             for (int i = 0; i < sonuc.length(); i++) {
                 JSONObject c = sonuc.getJSONObject(i);

                  AdayNumara = c.getString(TAG_OY);
                  ToplamOy = c.getString(TAG_TOPLAM);

                 Log.i("Aday Numaraları", AdayNumara);
                 Log.i("Oy Sayısı", ToplamOy);



                 pie.addItem(AdayNumara,Float.valueOf(ToplamOy), pRenk.get(i));

                 adaylar = jsonObj2.getJSONArray(TAG_ADAYLAR);
                for(int j=0; j< adaylar.length(); j++){

                    JSONObject c2 = adaylar.getJSONObject(j);

                    String no = c2.getString(TAG_NO);
                    String ad = c2.getString(TAG_AD);
                    String soyad = c2.getString(TAG_SOYAD);
                    String resim = c2.getString(TAG_RESIM);



                    HashMap<String, String> aday = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    do{
                    aday.put(TAG_AD, ad);
                    aday.put(TAG_SOYAD, soyad);
                    aday.put(TAG_RESIM, resim);
                    aday.put(TAG_NO, no);
                    aday.put(TAG_TOPLAM, ToplamOy);

                    adayList.add(aday);} while(AdayNumara == no);
                    }

                     adapter=new LazyAdapter2(SecimSonuclari.this, adayList);        
                     lv.setAdapter(adapter);
              }



          }catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }


         }
```

Code is probably has wrong approachs since I'm new to Android.

What I am getting now is for value in listview. There must be 2. The first two has same value like 1 and 1 on their number line. The second couple has the other number, lets say 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem. It appears to using "==" is wrong.

```
if(AdayNumara.equals(no)){
                        aday.put(TAG_AD, ad);
                        aday.put(TAG_SOYAD, soyad);
                        aday.put(TAG_RESIM, resim);
                        aday.put(TAG_NO, no);
                        aday.put(TAG_TOPLAM, ToplamOy);

                        adayList.add(aday);

                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question in a year old, but anyway...
I needed to compare two `JSONObject` values without internal `JSONObject`/`JSONArray`. Most SO solutions recommend a 3-rd party java library, which would be a bit too heavy.

First of all, the Android's built-in `JSONObject` ***does not*** define *hashCode()* and *equals()* in any sensible way. I used a wrapper class with a `JSONObject` inside.

The below functions are placed in some utility class, it is a trivial exercise to use them to define *hashCode()* and *equals()*.

```
public static int jsonHashCode(JSONObject j) {
    if (j == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    int res = 0;
    for (String s : new AsIterable<String>(j.keys())) {
        res += s.hashCode();
    }
    return res;
}
public static boolean comparesEqual(JSONObject x, JSONObject y, Collection<String>only, Collection<String>except) {
    Set<String> keys = keySet(x);
    keys.addAll(keySet(y));
    if (only != null) {
        keys.retainAll(only);
    }
    if (except != null) {
        keys.removeAll(except);
    }
    for (String s : keys) {
        Object a = null, b = null;
        try {
            a = x.get(s);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }
        try {
            b = x.get(s);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }
        if (a != null) {
            if (!a.equals(b)) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (b != null) {
            if (!b.equals(a)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
public static Set<String> keySet(JSONObject j) {
    Set<String> res = new TreeSet<String>();
    for (String s : new AsIterable<String>(j.keys())) {
        res.add(s);
    }
    return res;
}
```

where `AsIterable` lets us use the `for(:)` loop with an iterator and is defined as:

```
public class AsIterable<T> implements Iterable<T> {
    private Iterator<T> iterator;
    public AsIterable(Iterator<T> iterator) {
        this.iterator = iterator;
    }
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return iterator;
    }
}
```

You are welcome to write and post the recursive version of this code, supporting `JSONObject`/`JSONArray` values.

Answer (score 0):

For my use case, I ended up iterating over the keys of the first json object and checked to see if the value matched what was in the second json object.

```
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("some json string");
            JSONObject comparison = new JSONObject("some other json string with the same data but different key order");

            boolean equal = true;
            for (Iterator<String> iterator = obj.keys(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
                String curKey = iterator.next();
                if(!obj.getString(curKey).equals(comparison.getString(curKey))){
                    equal = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(equal){
                // do the thing that i want to do if the two objs are equal
            }
```